# Is there another abstraction level on top of SQLAlchemy ORM that only exposes "real" models?

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

Not sure if this is a reasonable idea, but here goes. SQLAlchemy has an Object-relational mapping, which means classes are directly mapped to database tables. However, I feel this still doesn't properly abstract the database away because it still relies on its structural features - e.g. when I need an n-to-m relationship, I need an extra table that I need to define with a class that, in the context of the program, doesn't actually model anything that should be considered an object in OOP. I also need to manually set a foreign key `something_id` and then a `backref=something` to the other class. What I would like is something like this:

```
class Publisher:
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Author:
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Book:
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String)
    publisher = Column(Publisher,reverse_reference="books")
    # this converts into a foreign key and adds the "books" attribute to the Publisher object

    authors = Multiple(Author,reverse_reference="books")
    # this creates a new table and adds the "books" attribute to the Author object
```

I tried implementing this manually with a wrapper class, but it gets extremely inelegant and clunky very quickly, so I thought I'd ask first if there is already something that does this or some better way I should be doing this.

Comment: It’s a feature of the ORM that it _doesn’t_ abstract away the fact that you are working with a relational database. You can read more about that in the early paragraphs [here](https://www.aosabook.org/en/sqlalchemy.html).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thank you for the link. Is there any other ORM library that *does* abstract that fact away?